# MySQL Default Sort Order with Limits and Offsets - Some Items Ignored - Why?

Tags: mysql, sql, limit, offset

I ran into a very interesting MySQL query issue that only seems to apply when no sorting order is specified and limits & offsets are used in the query.  One of the items from my table is repeated as a result when no sorting order is specified.  This doesn't seem to make sense based on how the ordering should work.

I've created a simple database and was able to reproduce the original problem I ran into:

Structure:
[image]

Data:
[image]

When using SQL queries such as:

`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM test WHERE test_customer = '1' LIMIT 4 OFFSET 4`

As I adjust the offset, the value "yes" doesn't appear in the last offset query.  Element 13 is repeated.  That doesn't seem to make sense.

Anyone know why this happening?

For a more detailed explanation of what's going on, please see this full example that shows the default results versus ascending order results:

https://eamster.tk/mysql_debug_test/mysql_debug.php

Any help is appreciated.  I'm just trying to understand what's going on... for now, I'll just work around the issue by specifying the `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL tables and result sets (with no `ORDER BY)` represent *unordered* sets.  Ordering is arbitrary and capricious.  It can change from query execution to query execution.

This query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
FROM test
WHERE test_customer = '1'
LIMIT 4 OFFSET 4;
```

Returns an arbitrary 4 rows for the customer.  The `OFFSET` means nothing.

If you want data in a particular order, then use `ORDER BY`.  Otherwise, the data is in an arbitrary order that can change from query execution to query execution.  There is no "default ordering".

So:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
FROM test
WHERE test_customer = 1
ORDER BY testid
LIMIT 4 OFFSET 4;
```

Note that I removed the single quotes from the `=`.  The value is an integer, so use a numeric constant.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation.  Too bad the ordering isn't inferred by the primary key index (if there is one) or the first int based column it runs across as the default sort ordering.

Comment: @OwN . . . No, it is not too bad at all.  It is too bad that you don't understand set theory and relational algebra, which are the historical influences on SQL.